# If isnt set open txt name else

Tags: php

**Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is, if the user hasn't selected one of the dropdown options, then a default .txt is opened, read and displayed.** When the user does decide on a drop down option, it echos the users option. It works by getting the value of the option and setting that to a variable to set the open path.

Instead of opening my default which is 'example' when the user hasnt selected, it seems to pick one of the values at random and select it.

- If the user hasnt selected an option, the default file path is p-changelog/example.txt
- If the user has chosen and option, the file path becomes p-changelog/$userOp.txt (UserOp being the users option from the drop down).

  ```
  if(!isset($_POST['userDateOp'])) {
    $userOp = "example";
  }else{
    $userOp = $_POST['userDateOp'];
  }
  if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $changelog = fopen("p-changelog/$userOp.txt", 'r');
    $pageTxt = fread($changelog, 25000);
    echo nl2br($pageTxt);
  }
  ```

**Entire Page:** [Code](http://pastebin.com/3Kf1zw7E)

I am new to PHP before criticising anything I've done.

Comment: We need to see your HTML form code as well.  What page is this PHP code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userDateOp` is always going to be set, as its posted every time.

What you are looking for is its value being empty

That function is

```
if(empty($_POST['userDateOp'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if submit is set because you've already validated the existence of `userDateOp`. So this will only lead to an undefined variable notice for `$changelog` for default.

Your simplified script should be

```
if(!isset($_POST['userDateOp'])) {
  $userOp = "example";
}else{
  $userOp = $_POST['userDateOp'];
}

$changelog = fopen("p-changelog/$userOp.txt", 'r');
$pageTxt = fread($changelog, 25000);
echo nl2br($pageTxt);
```